# Selenium to Data Frame to export to CSV

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a problem with getting all my data in my data frame, so the same into the CSV

I have this code:

```
class Table:

def __init__(self, driver):

    self.driver = driver

def get_column_info(self):

    column_info = []
    columns = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th")
    for column in columns:
        column_info.append(str(column.text.replace("%","")))
        writer2.writerow(column_info)
    return column_info


def get_results(self, index=None):

   columns = self.get_column_info()
   data = {}
   elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'resumen_mensual']/table/tbody[@id = 'body_tmes' ]/tr[contains(@class, 'ini')]{}"
                                                .format("[{}]".format(index) 

    for element in elements:
       current_index = elements.index(element) + 1 if not index else index
       parsed_data = {}
       for column in columns:
           value = element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'resumen_mensual']/table/tbody[@id = 'body_tmes' ]/tr[contains(@class, 'ini')][{}]"
                                                  "/td[{}]"
                                                  .format(current_index,columns.index(column) + 1)).text

           parsed_data.update({column: str(value)})
       data.update(parsed_data)

   return data
```

My output is the following:

[{'DÍA': '30', 'T. MEDIA': '25 °C', 'T. MÁX': '35 °C', 'T. MÍN': '15 °C', 'V. MEDIA VIENTO': '4.3 km/h', 'RACHAS MÁX': '-- km/h', 'PRESIÓN MEDIA': '1012 hPa', 'LLUVIA': '-- mm'}]

Which is just the last row of data I extracted from a table in a website

And if I modify my code this way (The modification is in the data.update):

```
 for element in elements:
       current_index = elements.index(element) + 1 if not index else index
       parsed_data = {}
       for column in columns:
           value = element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'resumen_mensual']/table/tbody[@id = 'body_tmes' ]/tr[contains(@class, 'ini')][{}]"
                                                  "/td[{}]"
                                                  .format(current_index,columns.index(column) + 1)).text

           parsed_data.update({column: str(value)})
       data.update({current_index:  parsed_data})

   return data
```

I get this:

[{1: {'DÍA': '1', 'T. MEDIA': '14 °C', 'T. MÁX': '19 °C', 'T. MÍN': '8 °C', 'V. MEDIA VIENTO': '9.1 km/h', 'RACHAS MÁX': '-- km/h', 'PRESIÓN MEDIA': '1027.3 hPa', 'LLUVIA': '-- mm'}, 2: {'DÍA': '2', 'T. MEDIA': '17 °C', 'T. MÁX': '22 °C', 'T. MÍN': '9 °C', 'V. MEDIA VIENTO': '6.4 km/h', 'RACHAS MÁX': '-- km/h', 'PRESIÓN MEDIA': '1026.4 hPa', 'LLUVIA': '-- mm'},.................... until 30

So basically I need all the rows, but I dont want the number of rows (Bold italic numbers marked) to appear between my data, so what can I do?

[{***1:*** {'DÍA': '1', 'T. MEDIA': '14 °C', 'T. MÁX': '19 °C', 'T. MÍN': '8 °C', 'V. MEDIA VIENTO': '9.1 km/h', 'RACHAS MÁX': '-- km/h', 'PRESIÓN MEDIA': '1027.3 hPa', 'LLUVIA': '-- mm'}, ***2:*** {'DÍA': '2', 'T. MEDIA': '17 °C', 'T. MÁX': '22 °C', 'T. MÍN': '9 °C', 'V. MEDIA VIENTO': '6.4 km/h', 'RACHAS MÁX': '-- km/h', 'PRESIÓN MEDIA': '1026.4 hPa', 'LLUVIA': '-- mm'},***3:*** {'DÍA': '3.................

What should I change, I know it has to be with the loop, but I cant figure it out

Comment: UI table contain `1:`?

Comment: What does UI mean? sorry, Im  new at this

Comment: On the web app the table contain that `1:`?

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a dictionary and that works in key-value pair.

here you are having two dictionaries

1. `parsed_data`
2. `data`

So in first case `data.update(parsed_data)` you are getting only last value because you are updating `data` dictionary with `parsed_data` dictionary element and its being overridden every time.

In second case you are making key as unique `current_index` for each dictionary(`parsed_data`) that being added to `data` and that's why you are seeing all records with unique key per dictionary(`parsed_data`).